# Select2 not visible when created as a Vue component

Tags: jquery-select2, vue.js, jquery-select2-4, vue-component

I've created a [vue.js](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html) component for a [select2](https://select2.github.io/) jquery component
The problem with the component is that the select is **invisible** (not shown) if the component's template is just the raw select:

```
<select v-select2="val">
</select>
```

(using the chrome inspector, I can see the select is effectively converted to a select2 by the jquery plugin BUT with 1x1 px dimensions)

... the problem is that everything works if I wrap the select with a DIV at the template:

```
<div>
  <select v-select2="val">
  </select>
</div>
```

I'm using a vue's directive (v-select2) to transform the select into a select2

Here it's the full code https://jsfiddle.net/futuretelematics/tkL8zxby/

Comment: I guess the problem has to do with the component template using a vue's directive to transform the select to a select2


    <select v-select2='val'></select>

If a directive is NOT used and the select is converted into a select2 when creating the component, everything goes OK:

https://jsfiddle.net/futuretelematics/a2kmhw64/2/

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be connected with the fact that `select2` hides original `select`, creates new `span` and appends it next to the original one. You end up with a fragment instance as described in [Vue.js documentation](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Fragment-Instance) which is discouraged.

> It is therefore recommended to always have a single root-level, plain element in templates.